# Accessing static content from css file with Google App Engine/Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, css, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a Google Cloud Storage bucket from which my Google App Engine Django application retrieves its static content. This works swimmingly as long as the content is being accessed through `staticfiles`, but becomes a problem when I try to link src urls through my css (e.g. background image, font). In my bucket logs I can see this is because no authentication info is being passed in the request for these assets being linked via CSS, whereas those grabbed through the static system (e.g. `staticfiles` or `{% static '<asset>' %}` )

I'm wondering what the correct solution is to this RATHER than just using inline CSS within the HTML to invoke the `staticfiles` system as doing so is bad practice.

This is my current approach, I can see it requesting the correct bucket resource, it just isn't authenticating:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "syne":;
    src: url("path/to/font.ttf") format("truetype")
}
```

Comment: How about just making those urls publicly accessible and then using the direct links (public urls) in your css files? This way, they don't have to go 'through' your App but are served directly by Google

Comment: @NoCommandLine I may just go this way. Feels weird to unconditionally expose content but I guess there's no material difference. Thanks!